# How many copies of $P_3$ are there in $K_7$ and $K_4$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How many copies of $P_3$ are there in $K_7$ and $K_4$?

For $K_7$, to pick $4$ vertices from $7$ it is $^7C_4$. I don't know how to proceed from here. I got to $105$ but I think it is wrong.

For $K_4$, to pick $4$ vertices from $4$ it is $^4C_4 = 1$. Looking at a sketch of $K_4$ it is clear that there are $2$ possible graphs of $P_3$. What would be the way of reaching this answer without sketching as that's my problem in the top one where it is too long to sketch and conclude ?

Comment: I find many more than $2$ copies of P3 in K4.  If you find the rest it will give you intuition for K7

Comment: @RossMillikan I tried again I reached $12$. I did $4!/(4-4)!$=$24$ but then divided by $2$ as it counted each copy twice.

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Is the other one $105$? @RossMillikan

Comment: No, once you have chosen the four vertices to use you are back to the K4 case on those four.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Relatively $K7$:**

First, we must choose one vertex which will play a role of the middle vertex of that $P3$ because we deal with $7$ vertices: $\binom{7}{1}$ ways.

Second, we have to pick two last vertices which will play a role of the two end vertices, but we have already choosen one vertex, therefore, only $6$ vertices are available to us: $\binom{6}{2}$.

**Such steps must be applied to $K4$.**

Therefore, we will have for $K7$: ${\binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{2}}$, for $K4$: ${\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}}$.

Comment: Can you explain why those formulae work please with an explanation ? Then I can accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: Does that method always work for any scenario of Kn and Pn?

Comment: Another approach that works for any Kn and Pm is to pick the m vertices to use $n \choose m$, then to put them in order m!, then to note you have counted every path twice because you can start at either end $\frac 12$.  Overall, $\frac 12{n \choose m}m!=\frac {n!}{2(n-m)!}$

Comment: @RossMillikan Aren't there $m+1$ vertices though for a path $Pm$ ?

Comment: @NikitaMazepin:  yes.  It becomes $\frac 12 {n \choose m+1}(m+1)!=\frac {n!}{(n-m-1)!}$

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks. I think there should be a divide by $2$ in your final equation. Even then, I am getting a different number for $K7$ when using Vadim's method

Comment: @NikitaMazepin:  Yes, the $\frac 12$ got dropped.  It is a pity we can't edit comments after 5 minutes.  He is taking P3 to have $3$ vertices, so two edges.